# How to upload a media file from a remote server to Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Is there any way of uploading a media file to Wordpress by entering a URL instead of a local file? I tried to search Wordpress plugins but with no luck. Is it possible in Wordpress to build a plugin that would handle this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this plugin
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/remote-images-grabber/

which does the job perfectly

The plugin only uploads image files.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. I was having the same problem but now i found this plugin and it works just fine. its called "remote upload"

here is the link to the file  " http://codecanyon.net/item/remote-upload-wordpress-plugin/3159604 "

Answer (score 1):

You can (and I think you have been able to for a while). The media library tool was recently just improved in native WP too.

If you click on the add media button above the post creation WYSIWIG editor, there's a tab for upload from URL.

Comment: I tried it and it did not upload the file to the website's server. It just added a link to the file inside the post itself.

Comment: Ah, you're right. It just links to the old copy. I did find this plugin though which may be helpful: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-linked-images-to-gallery-v01/